# How to use the Keycloak jboss/keycloak:15.0.2 docker image?

Tags: docker, keycloak, docker-image

I am currently using Keycloak v11 running in a docker container. I would like to migrate to v15 but I want to test it before migrating. I pull the last docker image jboss/keycloak:15.0.2 and simply run:

```
docker run -d -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin -p 8080:8080  --name kc-v15 jboss/keycloak:15.0.2
```

When I take a look at the logs I have multiple warnings and errors. The full stacktrace is below
Any help will be appreciated.

```
21:14:50,555 WARN  [org.infinispan.topology.ClusterTopologyManagerImpl] (thread-8,ejb,04cbb180fd8b) ISPN000329: Unable to read rebalancing status from coordinator 8eb22ce71ea3: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217: Received exception from 8eb22ce71ea3, see cause for remote stack trace
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:331)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:346)
        at org.jboss.as.clustering.common@23.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.clustering.context.ContextualExecutor$1.run(ContextualExecutor.java:70)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217: Received exception from 8eb22ce71ea3, see cause for remote stack trace
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.ResponseCollectors.wrapRemoteException(ResponseCollectors.java:25)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.impl.SingleTargetRequest.onResponse(SingleTargetRequest.java:43)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unknown command id 90!
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.marshall.exts.ThrowableExternalizer.readObject(ThrowableExternalizer.java:181)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.marshall.exts.ThrowableExternalizer.readObject(ThrowableExternalizer.java:42)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.objectFromByteBuffer(GlobalMarshaller.java:221)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.processResponse(JGroupsTransport.java:1394)
        ... 29 more

21:14:50,569 WARN  [org.infinispan.topology.ClusterTopologyManagerImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) ISPN000329: Unable to read rebalancing status from coordinator 8eb22ce71ea3: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217: Received exception from 8eb22ce71ea3, see cause for remote stack trace
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:331)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1348)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217: Received exception from 8eb22ce71ea3, see cause for remote stack trace
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.ResponseCollectors.wrapRemoteException(ResponseCollectors.java:25)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.ValidSingleResponseCollector.withException(ValidSingleResponseCollector.java:37)
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unknown command id 90!
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.marshall.exts.ThrowableExternalizer.readObject(ThrowableExternalizer.java:181)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.objectFromObjectInput(GlobalMarshaller.java:192)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.objectFromByteBuffer(GlobalMarshaller.java:221)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.processResponse(JGroupsTransport.java:1394)
        ... 29 more

21:14:50,573 WARN  [org.infinispan.topology.ClusterTopologyManagerImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) ISPN000329: Unable to read rebalancing status from coordinator 8eb22ce71ea3: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217: Received exception from 8eb22ce71ea3, see cause for remote stack trace
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:331)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217: Received exception from 8eb22ce71ea3, see cause for remote stack trace
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.ResponseCollectors.wrapRemoteException(ResponseCollectors.java:25)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.ValidSingleResponseCollector.withException(ValidSingleResponseCollector.java:37)
        at org.jboss.as.clustering.common@23.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.clustering.context.ContextualExecutor$1.run(ContextualExecutor.java:70)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unknown command id 90!
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.objectFromObjectInput(GlobalMarshaller.java:192)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.objectFromByteBuffer(GlobalMarshaller.java:221)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.processResponse(JGroupsTransport.java:1394)
        ... 29 more

21:14:50,590 WARN  [org.infinispan.topology.ClusterTopologyManagerImpl] (thread-7,ejb,04cbb180fd8b) ISPN000329: Unable to read rebalancing status from coordinator 8eb22ce71ea3: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217: Received exception from 8eb22ce71ea3, see cause for remote stack trace
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:331)
        at org.jboss.as.clustering.common@23.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.clustering.context.ContextualExecutor$1.run(ContextualExecutor.java:70)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217: Received exception from 8eb22ce71ea3, see cause for remote stack trace
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.ResponseCollectors.wrapRemoteException(ResponseCollectors.java:25)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.impl.SingleTargetRequest.addResponse(SingleTargetRequest.java:73)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.impl.SingleTargetRequest.onResponse(SingleTargetRequest.java:43)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unknown command id 90!
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.marshall.exts.ThrowableExternalizer.readObject(ThrowableExternalizer.java:181)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.objectFromObjectInput(GlobalMarshaller.java:192)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.objectFromByteBuffer(GlobalMarshaller.java:221)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.processResponse(JGroupsTransport.java:1394)
        ... 29 more

21:14:50,590 WARN  [org.infinispan.topology.ClusterTopologyManagerImpl] (thread-8,ejb,04cbb180fd8b) ISPN000329: Unable to read rebalancing status from coordinator 8eb22ce71ea3: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217: Received exception from 8eb22ce71ea3, see cause for remote stack trace
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:331)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:346)
        at org.jboss.as.clustering.common@23.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.clustering.context.ContextReferenceExecutor.execute(ContextReferenceExecutor.java:49)
        at org.jboss.as.clustering.common@23.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.clustering.context.ContextualExecutor$1.run(ContextualExecutor.java:70)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217: Received exception from 8eb22ce71ea3, see cause for remote stack trace
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.ResponseCollectors.wrapRemoteException(ResponseCollectors.java:25)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.ValidSingleResponseCollector.withException(ValidSingleResponseCollector.java:37)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.ValidSingleResponseCollector.addResponse(ValidSingleResponseCollector.java:21)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.impl.SingleTargetRequest.addResponse(SingleTargetRequest.java:73)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.impl.SingleTargetRequest.onResponse(SingleTargetRequest.java:43)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unknown command id 90!
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.marshall.exts.ThrowableExternalizer.readObject(ThrowableExternalizer.java:181)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.readNullableObject(GlobalMarshaller.java:358)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.objectFromObjectInput(GlobalMarshaller.java:192)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.objectFromByteBuffer(GlobalMarshaller.java:221)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.processResponse(JGroupsTransport.java:1394)
        ... 29 more

21:18:51,056 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) MSC000001: Failed to start service org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container.keycloak: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container.keycloak: org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManagerStartupException: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: Error starting component org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManager
        at org.wildfly.clustering.service@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.service.FunctionalService.start(FunctionalService.java:66)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1348)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManagerStartupException: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: Error starting component org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManager
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.internalStart(DefaultCacheManager.java:751)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.start(DefaultCacheManager.java:717)
        at org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan@23.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.subsystem.CacheContainerServiceConfigurator.get(CacheContainerServiceConfigurator.java:123)
        at org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan@23.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.subsystem.CacheContainerServiceConfigurator.get(CacheContainerServiceConfigurator.java:76)
        at org.wildfly.clustering.service@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.service.FunctionalService.start(FunctionalService.java:63)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: Error starting component org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManager
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:560)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.internalStart(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:341)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.start(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:237)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.internalStart(DefaultCacheManager.java:746)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217: Received exception from 8eb22ce71ea3, see cause for remote stack trace
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.invokeStart(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:592)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.doStartWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:583)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:552)
        ... 40 more
Caused by: org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217: Received exception from 8eb22ce71ea3, see cause for remote stack trace
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.ResponseCollectors.wrapRemoteException(ResponseCollectors.java:25)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.ValidSingleResponseCollector.withException(ValidSingleResponseCollector.java:37)
        at org.jboss.as.clustering.common@23.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.clustering.context.ContextualExecutor$1.run(ContextualExecutor.java:70)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unknown command id 85!
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.marshall.exts.ThrowableExternalizer.readObject(ThrowableExternalizer.java:181)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.objectFromObjectInput(GlobalMarshaller.java:192)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.objectFromByteBuffer(GlobalMarshaller.java:221)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.processResponse(JGroupsTransport.java:1394)
        ... 29 more

21:18:51,123 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) MSC000001: Failed to start service org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.ejb.http-remoting-connector: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.ejb.http-remoting-connector: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: Error starting component org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManager
        at org.wildfly.clustering.service@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.service.FunctionalService.start(FunctionalService.java:66)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: Error starting component org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManager
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:560)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.start(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:237)
        at org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.spi@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.spi.service.CacheServiceConfigurator.get(CacheServiceConfigurator.java:55)
        at org.wildfly.clustering.service@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.service.FunctionalService.start(FunctionalService.java:63)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217: Received exception from 8eb22ce71ea3, see cause for remote stack trace
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.util.concurrent.CompletionStages.join(CompletionStages.java:82)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.invokeStart(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:592)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.doStartWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:583)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:552)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217: Received exception from 8eb22ce71ea3, see cause for remote stack trace
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.ResponseCollectors.wrapRemoteException(ResponseCollectors.java:25)
        at org.jboss.as.clustering.common@23.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.clustering.context.ContextualExecutor$1.run(ContextualExecutor.java:70)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unknown command id 85!
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.marshall.exts.ThrowableExternalizer.readObject(ThrowableExternalizer.java:181)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.marshall.exts.ThrowableExternalizer.readObject(ThrowableExternalizer.java:42)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.objectFromByteBuffer(GlobalMarshaller.java:221)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.processResponse(JGroupsTransport.java:1394)
        ... 29 more

21:18:51,249 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "infinispan"),
    ("cache-container" => "keycloak")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container.keycloak" => "org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManagerStartupException: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: Error starting component org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManager
    Caused by: org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217: Received exception from 8eb22ce71ea3, see cause for remote stack trace
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unknown command id 85!"}}
21:18:51,255 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "ejb3"),
    ("service" => "remote")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.ejb.http-remoting-connector" => "org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: Error starting component org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManager
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: Error starting component org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManager
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217: Received exception from 8eb22ce71ea3, see cause for remote stack trace
    Caused by: org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217: Received exception from 8eb22ce71ea3, see cause for remote stack trace
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unknown command id 85!"}}
21:18:51,258 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "infinispan"),
    ("cache-container" => "keycloak"),
    ("thread-pool" => "async-operations")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container.keycloak" => "org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManagerStartupException: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: Error starting component org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManager
    Caused by: org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManagerStartupException: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: Error starting component org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManager
    Caused by: org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217: Received exception from 8eb22ce71ea3, see cause for remote stack trace
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unknown command id 85!"}}
21:18:51,261 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "infinispan"),
    ("cache-container" => "keycloak"),
    ("thread-pool" => "blocking")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container.keycloak" => "org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManagerStartupException: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: Error starting component org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManager
    Caused by: org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217: Received exception from 8eb22ce71ea3, see cause for remote stack trace
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unknown command id 85!"}}
21:18:51,261 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "infinispan"),
    ("cache-container" => "keycloak"),
    ("thread-pool" => "expiration")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container.keycloak" => "org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManagerStartupException: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: Error starting component org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManager
    Caused by: org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217: Received exception from 8eb22ce71ea3, see cause for remote stack trace
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unknown command id 85!"}}
21:18:51,261 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "infinispan"),
    ("cache-container" => "keycloak"),
    ("thread-pool" => "listener")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container.keycloak" => "org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManagerStartupException: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: Error starting component org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManager
    Caused by: org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManagerStartupException: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: Error starting component org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManager
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unknown command id 85!"}}
21:18:51,262 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "infinispan"),
    ("cache-container" => "keycloak"),
    ("thread-pool" => "non-blocking")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container.keycloak" => "org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManagerStartupException: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: Error starting component org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManager
    Caused by: org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217: Received exception from 8eb22ce71ea3, see cause for remote stack trace
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unknown command id 85!"}}
21:18:51,263 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "infinispan"),
    ("cache-container" => "keycloak"),
    ("thread-pool" => "persistence")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container.keycloak" => "org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManagerStartupException: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: Error starting component org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManager
    Caused by: org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManagerStartupException: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: Error starting component org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManager
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unknown command id 85!"}}
21:18:51,264 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "infinispan"),
    ("cache-container" => "keycloak"),
    ("thread-pool" => "remote-command")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container.keycloak" => "org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManagerStartupException: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: Error starting component org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManager
    Caused by: org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManagerStartupException: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: Error starting component org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManager
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unknown command id 85!"}}
21:18:51,266 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "infinispan"),
    ("cache-container" => "keycloak"),
    ("thread-pool" => "state-transfer")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container.keycloak" => "org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManagerStartupException: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: Error starting component org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManager
    Caused by: org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217: Received exception from 8eb22ce71ea3, see cause for remote stack trace
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unknown command id 85!"}}
21:18:51,266 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "infinispan"),
    ("cache-container" => "keycloak"),
    ("thread-pool" => "transport")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container.keycloak" => "org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManagerStartupException: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: Error starting component org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManager
    Caused by: org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManagerStartupException: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: Error starting component org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManager
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: Error starting component org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManager
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217: Received exception from 8eb22ce71ea3, see cause for remote stack trace
    Caused by: org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217: Received exception from 8eb22ce71ea3, see cause for remote stack trace
```

Comment: Are you trying to start a KC15 server to a running KC11 instance/cluster? Or have you powered all KC11 instances down before starting up a KC15 instance?

Comment: I tried to run it in my local dev machine for testing purposes

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this error is that I had another kc11 container running on my dev machine, stopping that container solved the issue. One of my questions is:
The goal of containers is isolation, so why a container impacts another one?